# Speech Recognition Part 1: Generate Training Data

Tags: python, performance, file, audio, data-visualization

You've all heard of [neural nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), no?  One of the "hello world"s of neural nets is [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) with the [MNIST dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database).  My idea for speech recognition is to train the neural net with short [labeled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170603/what-is-the-difference-between-labeled-and-unlabeled-data) [spectrograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) instead of characters.  Unfortunately I don't know of a database for doing this, so I have to create my own software for doing so.  Any suggestions on how to improve it?

*Note:*  Ultimately this is meant for real-time speech recognition, but when tested I couldn't plot and write spectrograms to file quickly enough for this to happen (as it interferes with how often the CPU can sample audio from the microphone).  I would be grateful for any solutions detailing how to improve performance in this area.

---

**main.py:**

```
from record import AudioHandler
import sys
import shutil
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    invalid = 0
    audio = AudioHandler()
    if os.path.isdir(audio.DATA_DIR):
        shutil.rmtree(audio.DATA_DIR) # clean folder
    while not invalid:
        try:
            invalid = audio.listen()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break

    audio.convert_fileblock()
    audio.save_all_audio()
    sys.exit()
```

**record.py:**

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import math
import time
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import scipy.io.wavfile
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_rms(block):
    try:
        rms = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(np.abs(block))))
    except Exception as e:
        print('RMS error: {}'.format(e))

    return rms

class AudioHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.DATA_DIR = 'raw_data'
        self.RATE = 16000
        self.INPUT_BLOCK_TIME = 0.03 # 30 ms
        self.CHANNELS = 1
        self.INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK = int(self.RATE * self.INPUT_BLOCK_TIME)
        self.SENTENCE_DELAY = 1.1 # seconds
        self.MAX_SILENT_BLOCKS = math.ceil(self.SENTENCE_DELAY / self.INPUT_BLOCK_TIME)
        self.THRESHOLD = 40 # dB
        self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.open_mic_stream()
        self.save_counter = '0'.zfill(8)
        self.silent_blocks = 0
        self.listening = False
        self.audio = []

    def stop(self):
        self.stream.close()

    def find_input_device(self):
        device_index = None
        for i in range( self.pa.get_device_count() ):
            devinfo = self.pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)

            for keyword in ['mic','input']:
                if keyword in devinfo['name'].lower():
                    print('Found an input: Device {} - {}'.format(i, devinfo['name']))
                    device_index = i
                    return device_index

        if device_index == None:
            print('No preferred input found; using default input device.')

        return device_index

    def open_mic_stream(self):
        device_index = self.find_input_device()

        stream = self.pa.open(  format = pyaudio.paInt16,
                                channels = self.CHANNELS,
                                rate = self.RATE,
                                input = True,
                                input_device_index = device_index,
                                frames_per_buffer = self.INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)

        return stream

    def save_block(self, snd_block):
        self.audio.append(snd_block)
        flat_block = np.hstack(snd_block)
        if not os.path.isdir(self.DATA_DIR):
            os.makedirs(self.DATA_DIR)
        np.savetxt('{}/block{}.txt'.format(self.DATA_DIR, self.save_counter), flat_block)
        self.save_counter = str(int(self.save_counter) + 1).zfill(8)

    def listen(self):
        try:
            raw_block = self.stream.read(self.INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK, False)
            snd_block = np.fromstring(raw_block, dtype=np.int16)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error recording: {}'.format(e))
            return

        amplitude = get_rms(snd_block)
        if amplitude > self.THRESHOLD:
            self.listening = True
            self.silent_blocks = 0 # reset counter
        else:
            self.silent_blocks += 1

        if self.listening:
            self.save_block(snd_block)
        if self.silent_blocks > self.MAX_SILENT_BLOCKS and self.listening:
            # remove last stored silent blocks
            for i in range(int(self.save_counter) - 1, int(self.save_counter) - self.MAX_SILENT_BLOCKS, -1):
                self.audio.pop()
                i = str(i).zfill(8)
                os.remove('{}/block{}.txt'.format(self.DATA_DIR, i))
            self.listening = False
            return True # done speaking

    def save_all_audio(self):
        flat_audio = np.hstack(self.audio)
        scipy.io.wavfile.write('{}/ALL.wav'.format(self.DATA_DIR), self.RATE, flat_audio)
        f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(flat_audio, fs=self.RATE, window='hanning', scaling='spectrum')
        fig = plt.pcolormesh(t, f, 10 * np.log10(1 + Sxx), cmap='gray')
        fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
        plt.savefig('{}/spec_all.png'.format(self.DATA_DIR), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)

    def convert_fileblock(self):
        block_counter = 0
        for file in glob.glob('{}/*.txt'.format(self.DATA_DIR)):
            block = np.loadtxt(file, dtype=np.int16)
            t0 = time.time()
            scipy.io.wavfile.write('{}/audio{}.wav'.format(self.DATA_DIR, block_counter), self.RATE, block)
            f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(block, fs=self.RATE, window='hanning', scaling='spectrum')
            plt.figure(figsize=(self.INPUT_BLOCK_TIME, self.RATE / 4000), dpi = 100)
            fig = plt.pcolormesh(t, f, 10 * np.log10(1 + Sxx), cmap='gray')
            fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
            fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
            plt.savefig('{}/spec{}.png'.format(self.DATA_DIR, block_counter), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)
            plt.close()
            print('Time to process block{}: {}'.format(block_counter, time.time() - t0))
            block_counter += 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using `sys.exit`?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Initially that line of code was within the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, and lingered afterwards when I restructured the code.

Comment: Just as an FYI, you may find the data set available at http://voxforge.org/ handy.  You should also be aware that most speech recognition systems work on the [cepstrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum) of the sample rather than its spectrum.

Comment: @Jules Is there a dataset you know of that has pre-labeled spectrograms or cepstrums?  Also, can you point to an article saying why a cepstrum would be preferable to a spectrum?  I can't seem to find an article giving a reason.

Comment: Can't look at the code in detail right now, but a general comment: Transforming the data in a spectrogram is simply a transformation of what is already there. I'm not an expert on neural networks, but I guess such networks should be able to learn the required transform implicitly with 1D raw audio segments as input instead of 2D spectrograms. In image recognition networks often have 2D convolutional layers at the input, so I'd guess a audio recognition network could use 1D convolutional layers. There is also something called *recurrent neural networks* that are often used for sequential data.

Comment: @kazemakase We could feed these numbers right into a neural network, but trying to recognize speech patterns by processing these samples directly is difficult.  I figured since humans can read spectrograms (and not the raw dB data) with a little practice, so could a neural net.

Comment: Right. We humans are rather bad when it comes to seeing frequency components. But we are pretty good at hearing them. In fact, our hearing organ (the cochlear) works rather similar to a short time fourier transform. I think a part of the neural network could take over that functionality too. But that's probably just me thinking out of one box into another :)

Comment: Sticking with spectrograms, if the bottleneck is drawing/saving then don't draw and save them in real time. To generate training data you can record the audio and create the spectrograms offline. For applaying the procedure in real time you don't need to store the images. Just feed the data from the computing function into the network.

Comment: @kazemakase If you could post an answer detailing that within my posted, I would consider that a good code review.  Keep in mind I have to save off the data and somehow classify it myself so I can train the network.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have to admit that I have no idea what the purpose of the code is (never worked with speech recognition) but I know a little bit Python so I can give some advise on the code itself.

### Performance

You expressed the desire to optimize the performance of your script. But do you know the first [rule about optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimization)? If not, it is:

- Don't!

The second rule is:

- Don't... yet!

And the third rule is:

- Profile before optimizing.

Let me rephrase this: Without tests and profiling you (and I) will likely optimize the wrong part of the code and introduce a bug while doing so.

I personally like `pytest` and `line_profiler` but it doesn't matter what tools you choose. Just make sure you know where the bottlenecks are and that the program still works correctly after optimizing the bottlenecks. Before doing that I wouldn't worry about the performance just yet.

Instead, I'll focus on the structure of the code.

### Imports:

`struct` isn't used as far as I can see so why import it?

Also you import several packages so it wouldn't be a bad idea to sort them. I usually sort them alphabetically and seperate builtin modules from 3rd party modules, for example:

```
# Builtin modules
import glob
import math
import os
import time

# 3rd party modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import scipy.io.wavfile
from scipy import signal
```

The reason for the seperation is that it makes it easier to know which dependencies need to be installed to actually run the script.

### `try` and `except` in functions

Please have a look at your `get_rms` function: It's essentially a one-line numpy code that is guarded by a `try` and `except`.

First, it's great that you only catch `Exception` instead of having a bare `except`! But in case you ever get an exception you'll hit an `NameError` in the `return rms` line, just because the `try` didn't work and the `rms` variable wasn't defined.

Generally, just let the exception bubble up and let the caller figure out what to do when an exception happens. It's a helper function after all. So I would suggest just using:

```
def get_rms(block):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(block)))
```

I also removed the `np.abs` because `np.square` does return an absolute value itself, so the `np.abs` would be a no-op.

A bit of trivia: If you operate on **scalars** you can also use `math`-functions. `np.mean` returns a scalar, so you could use `math.sqrt` instead of `np.sqrt`. I mention this purely as trivia because it's unlikely that the overhead of `np.sqrt` will contribute significantly to the runtime of your program! But if you ever need to micro-optimize remember that `numpy` is amazingly fast for arrays but `math` is faster for scalars.

### Class attributes vs. instance attributes

You have a lot of constants in `__init__` and it's important to initialize **mutable** attributes in `__init__` (instead of as class attributes) but for **immutable** attributes it's generally easier to initialize them on the class. That's a matter of preference so this is just a suggestion:

```
class AudioHandler(object):

    DATA_DIR = 'raw_data'
    RATE = 16000
    INPUT_BLOCK_TIME = 0.03  # 30 ms
    CHANNELS = 1
    INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK = int(RATE * INPUT_BLOCK_TIME)
    SENTENCE_DELAY = 1.1  # seconds
    MAX_SILENT_BLOCKS = math.ceil(SENTENCE_DELAY / INPUT_BLOCK_TIME)
    THRESHOLD = 40  # dB

    def __init__(self):
        self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.open_mic_stream()
        self.save_counter = '0'.zfill(8)
        self.silent_blocks = 0
        self.listening = False
        self.audio = []
```

One further comment. If you use a context manager approach you might want to put the `self.stream = self.open_mic_stream()` line in the `__enter__` function instead of the `__init__`!

### `str.zfill` or `str.format`

I'm talking about the `save_counter` attribute. You initialize it as `str` but you regularly operate on it as `int`. With `str.format` you can easily modify the string-representation of an integer, so I would keep the `save_counter` as `int` and then format it when you need a string. For example:

```
>>> '{:0>8}'.format(10001)
'00010001'
```

This requires some changes throughout your code. For example in `save_block` you would need to change the last two lines to:

```
np.savetxt('{}/block{:0>8}.txt'.format(self.DATA_DIR, self.save_counter), flat_block)
self.save_counter += 1
```

But I feel this is more readable (and probably also a tiny bit faster).

### `return` in loops

In `find_input_device` you can easily get rid of the `device` variable because either you `return` inside the loop or the loop terminates without any match:

```
def find_input_device(self):
    for i in range(self.pa.get_device_count()):
        devinfo = self.pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)

        for keyword in ['mic','input']:
            if keyword in devinfo['name'].lower():
                print('Found an input: Device {} - {}'.format(i, devinfo['name']))
                return i

    print('No preferred input found; using default input device.')
    # return None is implicit!
```

### `enumerate`

In your `convert_fileblock` method I saw this:

```
block_counter = 0
for file in glob.glob('{}/*.txt'.format(self.DATA_DIR)):
    # ...
    block_counter += 1
```

There's a builtin iterator `enumerate` for this exactly this task:

```
for block_counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob('{}/*.txt'.format(self.DATA_DIR))):
    # ...
```

One small issue here: `file` isn't a good variable name. It's (1) the name of a [python2 builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) and (2) `filename` would be more descriptive anyway.

### `print` vs. `logging`

In most cases you never want to `print`. Depending on your preferences you should either `log`, `warn` or `raise`. For example in `find_input_device` the device message is not always important (except when debugging or when you want a verbose output). Instead you could use [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial):

```
logging.debug('Found an input: Device {} - {}'.format(i, devinfo['name']))
```

By default this message is hidden - except when you do something like:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

before you run your script.

### PEP8 and function calls

This:

```
    stream = self.pa.open(  format = pyaudio.paInt16,
                            channels = self.CHANNELS,
                            rate = self.RATE,
                            input = True,
                            input_device_index = device_index,
                            frames_per_buffer = self.INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
```

is breaking two PEP8 "rules":

- No whitespaces after `(`
- No whitespaces around `=` for keyword arguments

so this would look better as:

```
    stream = self.pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                          channels=self.CHANNELS,
                          rate=self.RATE,
                          input=True,
                          input_device_index=device_index,
                          frames_per_buffer=self.INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
```

and if you care about line-length you can also indent slightly differently:

```
    stream = self.pa.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=self.CHANNELS,
            rate=self.RATE,
            input=True,
            input_device_index=device_index,
            frames_per_buffer=self.INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
```

### [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-lbyl) and [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-eafp)

The `if not os.path.isdir(self.DATA_DIR)` in the `save_block` method is a red flag. It might work most of the time, but what if the directory was created shortly after this call and before the `os.makedirs` call?

Generally you should just try to create it and catch an exception if it already exists. In newer pythons `makedirs` supports an `exist_okay` parameter that simplifies this without using `try`, `except OSError`:

```
os.makedirs(self.DATA_DIR, exist_ok=True)
```

@Peilonrayz already mentioned this already so I won't go into the details of LBYL and EAFP. But generally EAFP is faster and more robust (and often also shorter). No wonder that it's the recommended style in python :-)

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

The methods `save_all_audio` and `convert_fileblock` share (at first glance) some common code:

```
scipy.io.wavfile.write(...)
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(...)
fig = plt.pcolormesh(...)
fig.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.savefig(...)
```

Probably this could be factored into a seperate (private) method that is called by both methods.

### More context managers

You timed a part of your script using `t0 = time.time()`, `print('Time to process block{}: {}'.format(block_counter, time.time() - t0))`. I would suggest creating a context manager for this task because that way you can see easily what is being timed (because it is indented) and you could reuse it whenever you want to time something else:

```
import time

class Timer():
    def __enter__(self):
        self._starttime = time.time()

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        time_elapsed = time.time() - self._starttime
        print(time_elapsed)  # or "logging.debug", see above
```

An example:

```
with Timer():
    time.sleep(2)
```

Be warned that this context manager class adds some overhead but `time.time` isn't really suitable for "precise" perfomance analysis anyway. If you want to accuratly time some code the `timeit` module should be used instead.

### More comments!

Answer (score 7):

[PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) doesn't seem to have a `with` interface, however you should add that interface to your class. [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) explains why it was added to Python, but it mostly comes down to being syntactic sugar to a `try` `finally`. To add this is rather simple, you [add `__enter__` and `__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) and that's it. The benefit to this, is you don't have to manually close the stream, as you don't in main.py. And so I'd change your code to include:

```
class AudioHandler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = None
        self.save_counter = '0'.zfill(8)
        ...

    def __enter__(self):
        self.open()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close()
        return False

    def close(self):
        self.stream.close()

    def open(self):
        device_index = self.find_input_device()

        self.stream = self.pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                   channels=self.CHANNELS,
                                   rate=self.RATE,
                                   input=True,
                                   input_device_index=device_index,
                                   frames_per_buffer=self.INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)
```

---

I don't really know the libraries you're using and so I can't really comment on them, but I'd encourage a more EAFP rather than LBYL approach to file manipulation, so that you don't get [TOCTOU bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check-to-time-of-use).

I'd also not use `sys.exit`, and just leave Python to exit normally. I know this is a relic of earlier code, but I'd definitely recommend you remove it, as it normally is a red light.

And so all the above would change `main.py` roughly to (I've not tested it):

```
from record import AudioHandler
import shutil

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    invalid = 0
    with AudioHandler() as audio:
        shutil.rmtree(audio.DATA_DIR, ignore_errors=True)
        while not invalid:
            try:
                invalid = audio.listen()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break

        audio.convert_fileblock()
        audio.save_all_audio()
```

Comment: What is the `__close__` method for? Did you mean `__exit__`?

Comment: @MSeifert Edited it in, in the text he correctly said you need to define `__exit__`, so I guess it was just a typo (so many `close`s around there...).

Comment: Thank you @Graipher, 4AM coding isn't my strong suite, ):

Comment: Although you don't really need the `open` and `close` methods, you could move all the code there to the `__enter__` and `__exit__`methods

Comment: @Graipher I personally would keep them in. If you want to extend the class, then it's simpler and cleaner to use `open` and `close` rather than the Python internal dependent `__enter__` and `__exit__`. Also it wouldn't work without `with`, so like 2.5+ or something.